# Retrive value of radio button from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" id="sex" <?php if($sex=='Male') {echo 'checked' }; ?>/>Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" id="sex" <?php if($sex=='Female'){echo 'checked' ;} ?>  />Female
```

I want to retrieve values of radio buttons which i have select when submit the form for updating them.
Need instant solution

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $fname=$_REQUEST['t1'];
    $lname=$_REQUEST['t2'];
    $sex=$_REQUEST['sex'];
    $country=$_REQUEST['Country'];
    $hobby=$_REQUEST['check'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['Email'];
    $password=$_REQUEST['p1'];
    $repassword=$_REQUEST['p2'];


    if(isset($_REQUEST['update']))
    {

         $query = mysql_query("UPDATE registration SET First_Name='$fname', Last_Name='$lname', Sex='$sex', Country='$country', Hobbies='$hobby', Email='$email', Password='$password', Repassword='$repassword' where id='$editid'");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: i had used it and also $_REQUEST['sex] also but both are not working

Comment: Misread your question, what's the value of `$sex`?

Comment: Ok i am Editing my Question

Comment: Your input needs to be nested between form tags for the data to actually post. If this is the case please edit your post to show your HTML form.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<?php $sex= $row['sex']; ?> 

<td align="left" valign="middle">
<input name="sex" type="radio" id="sex" value="S" <?php echo ($sex== 'Male') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/> Male
<input name="sex" type="radio" id="sex" value="N" <?php echo ($sex== 'Female') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?>/> Female</td></td>
```

Comment: Whats "/> Male /> Female" suppose to do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to post your data to a php file

```
<form action="..." method="post">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" id="sex" <?php if($sex=='Male') {echo 'checked' }; ?>/>Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" id="sex" <?php if($sex=='Female'){echo 'checked' ;} ?>  />Female
</form>
```

then at the php file you will get the selected option value using this code;

```
<?php
.
.
.
if (isset($_POST['sex']) $value = $_POST['sex'];
```

and then you can save the value to your database. the $value varaiable would have the values  *Male* or *Female* as you typed them in the html input tags (in the value attribute).